# How to get attr_html per file or subtree in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, images, inline-image

I need all images in **org-mode displayed** with 40%. Means I need the file itself displaying the pictures small, **not the html export**. This works flawless by putting above every image:

```
#+attr_html: :width 40%
```

Now to avoid repeating the upper line above each image I tried setting the attribute per subtree to no avail:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:EXPORT_OPTIONS: attr_html: :width 40%
:END:
```

How can I set this globally per org file or per subtree?

Comment: I don't think this can be done in Org mode, but I'm pretty sure it can be done with CSS. Whenever you want to do something to *every* HTML element of a given type, CSS is the way to go.

Comment: I did not get a notification when you changed your question. In the future, you might want to add a comment that you did so.

Comment: @NickD Had already started writing a comment, yet stopped middle way. Thought there's no need to "outsmart" the algorithm. Gut feelings still prevail. Will gladly do as you suggested next time.

Comment: Yup - we live and learn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my comment, you can use CSS to do that per file (it is not possible however to limit the CSS to a subtree).

All you have to do is add this at the top of your file:

```org
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style> img { width: 40%; } </style>
```

EDIT: In answer to the modified question, set the variable `org-image-actual-width` to the width (an integer denoting the number of pixels) you want. To use a fraction of the text width, set it to a list whose car is that fraction:

```el
 (setq org-image-actual-width '(0.4))
```